# Qual o nome deste componente abaixo?

Tags: java, html, css, jsf, primefaces

Tem algum componente pronto com `primefaces` que faça o que a imagem ilustra abaixo? preciso fazer isso com `JSF` e estou meio perdido.

A idéia é que sim seja um auto complete, mas se ele não achar nada quero que ele mostre um com o value "Create Borda" e dai eu possa abrir um dialog

[image: component JSF]

Comment: Pronto não tem mas você pode personalizar um, eu acho.

Comment: O que é isto? Um autocomplete? Na imagem não da pra ter certeza do que é?

Answer (score 0):

O que chega mais próximo do que você está querendo é o autoComplete do primefaces, de uma olhada no showcase da bilbioteca, aqui está o link

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Espero que isso de ajude qualquer duvida pode perguntar via comentários

Comment: A idéia é que sim seja um auto complete, mas se ele não achar nada quero que ele mostre um com o value "Create Borda" e dai eu possa abrir um dialog